# Android youtube video playing

Tags: android, youtube

I want to play Youtube videos in my application. I saw several examples for this.
All of it launches a new activity with ACTION_VIEw or uses a web view.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http:....")))
```

So the problem i am facing is , along with the youtube video, i want to display a titile in my video activity. So this cannot be achived if i follow any of the above method.

Please help me by telling how can i start my activity so that i can have a textview and play the youtube video in it .

I have similar layout defined for non youtube videos where the layout has a textview and videoview.

For youtube videos is there a way to play it in video view .

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement your own UI bottom up for that buddy!